# Create and Request Array of Azure parameter function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to create an Array of Azure parameter function, but it's not working for me. For these, I tried below code.

**ABCBarCodes Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionApp4
{

    public class ALCBarCodes
    {

        public string BarCodeText { get; set; }
        public string BarCodeWidth { get; set; }
        public string BarCodeHeight { get; set; }
        public string BarCodeType { get; set; }
        public string BarCodeFont { get; set; }

    }

}
```

**Azure Function**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace FunctionApp4
{
    public static class Function4
    {
        [FunctionName("Function4")]
        public static HttpResponseMessage Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "Function4/{ALCBarCodes}")]HttpRequestMessage req, List<ALCBarCodes> list, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            // Fetching the name from the path parameter in the request URL
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, list);
        }
    }
}
```

On this case how can I request the URL?

I tried below URL but it's not working.

http://localhost:7071/api/Function4/1

Any help on this?

Comment: Is it a get or a post request?

Comment: @Kzrystof, Post

Comment: Could you remove the GET, change the route to Function4 and  then, try removing both the `req`? The collection of ALCBarCodes would be in the body of the POST request...

Comment: @Kzrystof I am a newbie. If possible give me any examples or reference links related to the above thread? It will help.

Comment: could you add a sample of the body you're trying to send ?

Comment: {"ALCBarCodes":["BarCodeText":"1234","BarCodeWidth":"90","BarCodeHeight":"1234","BarCodeFont":"12","BarCodeType":"128"]}

Comment: Why are you passing 1 after function name? try this http://localhost:7071/api/Function4  also it should be post not get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working piece. Please  try this

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Forum
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)]
            HttpRequestMessage req,
            TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            //dynamic input =await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>();

            ALCBarCodes[] input = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<ALCBarCodes[]>();

            // Fetching the name from the path parameter in the request URL
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, input);
        }
    }
    public class ALCBarCodes
    {
        public string BarCodeText { get; set; }
        public string BarCodeWidth { get; set; }
        public string BarCodeHeight { get; set; }
        public string BarCodeType { get; set; }
        public string BarCodeFont { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Sample  Input:

```
[
{
"BarCodeText": "1234",
"BarCodeWidth": "90",
"BarCodeHeight": "1234",
"BarCodeType": "128",
"BarCodeFont": "12"
},
{
"BarCodeText": "1234",
"BarCodeWidth": "90",
"BarCodeHeight": "1234",
"BarCodeType": "128",
"BarCodeFont": "12"
},
{
"BarCodeText": "1234",
"BarCodeWidth": "90",
"BarCodeHeight": "1234",
"BarCodeType": "128",
"BarCodeFont": "12"
}
]
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Azure is supporting OData?