# Get array of string from url query param with Python Azure Function App HTTP

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Python Func app with the URL below:

```
www.domain.com/api/url?users=[a,b,c]
```

I want to get the `users` as an array from the URL above in Python

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    get the users as an array from the URL
```

No answer from the link below

[Python HttpTrigger Azure Function url param as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59788653/python-httptrigger-azure-function-url-param-as-array)

Comment: try like this to fetch an array from query params `request.args.getlist(key)`. on url I think you need to pass as `key[]=1&key[]=2`

Comment: this is Azure Func app in Python, the `args` is not supported

Comment: this may help you `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55121783/create-and-request-array-of-azure-parameter-function`

Comment: thx, but it is .net in C#. I need a Python solution.

Answer (score -1):

> I want to get the `users` as an array from the URL above in Python

AFAIK, we can't get the query parameter as array by default it will be a string. It has either string or dictionary.

[image]

You can use [**urllib**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) module to get the query parameter. Here I have used to `urllib` to get the params which follows.

```py
import  logging
from  urllib  import  parse  as  urlparse
import  azure.functions  as  func  

def  main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    # get the req url with all information
    urldata =urlparse.urlsplit(req)

    # Get the query param
    queryparamdata = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlsplit(req).query)

    # convert that into dict
    params = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(urlparse.urlsplit(req).query))
```

The alternative way to get specific query param use

```py
# get specific param
# e.g. param_list = req.params.get('<Your param to get>')
name = req.params.get('name')
```

Refer [Why can't use arrays in query string](https://python.plainenglish.io/python-why-you-cant-use-arrays-in-query-strings-with-requests-and-urllib-and-how-to-fix-it-da0ad2ad2e06) blog created by Michael T. Andemeskel